# Evaluate the definite integral $\int_{-2}^0 \frac3{\sqrt{-x^2-2x}}\ dx.$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_{-2}^0 \frac3{\sqrt{-x^2-2x}}\ dx.$$

I have tried substituting the square root, but might have done the substitution wrong. I also end up with having to divide one by zero and don't really know what to do then (please see picture:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCqgA.jpg). Have I reasoned completely wrong? I'm be super grateful for any help.

/Nicklas

Comment: Wolfram gives the answer $3\pi$.

Comment: Do you know how to do in order to calculate it?

Comment: I've written an answer; it requires you to know that $\arcsin x+C$ is the antiderivative of $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: Then I see, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}\int_{-2}^0 \frac3{\sqrt{-x^2-2x}}\ dx&=3\int_{-2}^0\frac1{\sqrt{1-(x+1)^2}}\ dx\\
&=3\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\ du\\
&=3\arcsin u\ \bigg|_{-1}^1\\
&=3\left(\arcsin 1-\arcsin\left(-1\right)\right)\\
&=3\left(\frac{\pi}2-\left(-\frac{\pi}2\right)\right)\\
&=\boxed{3\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: I just wrote the same +1 :-)